# Creating and selecting a group programmatically with Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

Let's say I have a canvas containing 6 objects and a button outside of canvas.

When I click this button, 3 of this objects will to become a group and selected, objects will keep their positions relative to canvas.

Is that possible?

I tried so many things but could manage it to work. The solution that I'm looking for is something like below.

```
var objectList=[1,2,3];    
var newgroup = new fabric.Group();

$.each(objectList, function (i) {
    var obj = canvas.item(i);
    newgroup.add(obj.clone());
    canvas.remove(obj);
});

canvas.add(newgroup)
canvas.setActiveGroup(newgroup);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
(function() {
  var objectList = [1,2,3],
      group = new fabric.Group();

  canvas.forEachObject(function(o, i) {
    if (objectList.indexOf(i) > -1) {
      group.addWithUpdate(o);
      canvas.remove(o);
    }
  });
  canvas.setActiveObject(group);
  canvas.add(group);
})();
```

Only the objects at index 1, 2 or 3 are added to group.

Comment: Thank you @Kienz, it worked for me after i changed the line `canvas.setActiveObject(group);` with `canvas.setActiveGroup(group);`

Comment: is there any other way to active too many objects of canvas in group using fabric. @kangax

Comment: How to differentiate that group is create by using fabric.group or selecting multiple object using mouse in fabric js version 1.7.22?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the selected items as group produced weird results when redrawing connections to them afterwards for me.
fabic's ActiveSelection is the intended Group Object for programatically adding a Selection Group to Canvas now (probably didn't exist in 2013)

Here's my snipped that also works with following move events, it's selecting items based on two attributes 'issueType' and 'clusterIndex':

```
let allObjects = CANVAS.getObjects();
let selectedObjects = [];
for(let i=0;i < allObjects.length;i++){
    let object = allObjects[i];
    if(object.issueType && object.clusterIndex === clusterIndex){
        selectedObjects.push(object);
        }
    }
let selectionGroup = new fabric.ActiveSelection(selectedObjects);
CANVAS.add(selectionGroup);
CANVAS.setActiveObject(selectionGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var objectList = [1,2,3],
group = new fabric.Group(objectList);
```

the above code should would work for you
it will anyway group objects 1,2,3

all you have to do is to get rid of the original objects and group the clones