# string in the center of a circle - Fabrics.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I want to draw a colored circle with a number on its center. I wasn't able to find anything in the docs to achieve the same.

Any guidance in regards to this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this. May be this will save someone's precious time:

```
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 100,
  fill: '#eef',
  scaleY: 0.5,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
  fontSize: 30,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

var group = new fabric.Group([ circle, text ], {
  left: 150,
  top: 100,
  angle: -10
});

canvas.add(group);
```

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3

Comment: That is correct. If you want elements to be centered togheter, applying originX/Y to center and giving no top and left, is the easiest thing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a fabric.Circle object and fabric.Text object with the same left and top that are both center positioned.

```
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    top: 0, //Arbitrarily placed at top left corner
    left: 0,
    radius: 100,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

var text = new fabric.Text("Your number here", {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    fill: "#FFFFFF" // Circle background defaults to black, so make text visible
});

// Assuming you have a fabric.Canvas stored in canvas already
canvas.add(circle);
canvas.add(text);
```

Comment: Even I thought about that. But the problem with this approach is if the user moves the circle the text won't move with it. if this is the approach I take then I need to find a way to bind both the objects as one so that they can be manipulated together.

Comment: Maybe hook into the `object:selected` event for the canvas and whenever either object is selected, automatically add the other to a group with it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632006/creating-and-selecting-a-group-programmatically-with-fabric-js for doing this).  Otherwise, you'll probably need to create a custom class for this.